# how to handle "the referenced component "reference" could not be found."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, warnings

So i have never encountered this type of error(well warning) before and i am not sure how exactly to go about rectifying the issue. Of course due to this warning several errors come up when i attempt to call anything that requires this reference.

The warning i get is:

```
"the referenced component "Telerik.Web.UI" could not be found."
```

What my questions are about this problem, are what is the reason for Visual Studio to be unable to find a reference even though it appears to be there?

Is there something extra i need to obtain in order for this particular reference to work?

How exactly would i go about fixing this issue?

Also as a side question: how exactly would i have go about dealing with this issue for any reference with Visual Studio, or what would be the steps to go through in order to solve this problem?

**Update 1:**

Okay so after spending some time messing around with it i ended up just deleting the reference and readding it.

This solved the problem, however i am still interested in understanding why this would occur?

So new question to be considered: Why would a reference be considered as "not found" even though it is in the correct location?

**Update 2:**

Okay so continuing with reference issues, i found this one to be interesting and i have no idea why it is occuring. So my problem is that i am attempting to use the reference

> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

The pathway for this reference is:

```
C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\2.8\managed\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
```

So what i want to do is use this same reference, except instead of the 2.8\managed*

I want to use the version of this reference from the 4.0 directory in the commons directory. No problem all i have to do is delete the current reference and just manually browse for this in the 4.0 directory. However, when i do this i end up having the pathway in the properties folder continue to say it's coming from this location:

```
C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\2.8\managed\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
```

What i would like to know is why is this happening? Does it mean that i am still not obtainning the correct reference folder and how do  i go about correcting this problem?

Any help or suggestions on how to solve this problem are greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the assembly that contains this type to your Visual Studio project by right-clicking and 'Add Reference'?

Comment: Yup, The telerick reference was in the reference folder

Comment: Don't forget to use File + Save All so that the project file gets saved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project isn't configured to use the Client Profile.

Right click on your project and select Properties. Click the Application tab. In the "Target framework" box, select whatever framework you want to target, but the one without `Client profile` at the end.

This answer is a great resource that explains why the Client Profile can't be used in your case: [The referenced project x does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792222/the-referenced-project-x-does-not-exists/5792255#5792255)

Comment: the Target Framework is not a client profile, but thank you for your quick response and it will be something i'll look for, for future problems.

Comment: Sure. Do you have the proper `using` statements set up in your code?